# how to get creator and Owner info of Work item in RTC 4.0.4

Tags: rtc

how to get creator and Owner info of Work item in Rational Team Concert 4.0.4 using plain java lib  .The getOwner() method of *IWorkItem*  returns *IContributorHandle* type object which don't have any method to get name from this.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IContributor` should be better suited.
See [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/17571/icontributorhandle-to-icontributor):

> Every handle class has a corresponding Item class where the 'full info' is available (handle is just some sort of pointer).
>
> You can use the `IItemManager` (`ITeamRepository#itemManager()`) to resolve a handle to an item (e.g. from `IContributorHandle` to `IContributor`).

Something [like this](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/87561/how-to-get-username-out-of-its-uuid):

```
IContributorHandle wkspOwnerhandle = (IContributorHandle)data.getSourceWorkspace().getOwner();   
IItem contributerHandle = itemService.fetchItem(wkspOwnerhandle, null);
IContributor userid = (IContributor) contributerHandle.getFullState();
String userName = userid.getName();
```